# Why dictionary keys need the preceding slash

Tags: postscript

This works fine

```
/posX 200 def
posX 100 moveto
```

This doesn't work

```
/positions 1 dict def
positions begin
   /posX 200 def
end
positions posX get 100 moveto
```

After struggling for hours I stumbled upon the way to get it work

```
positions /posX get 100 moveto
```

Could someone explain why when using a dictionary key one needs to retain the slash?

I looked in the reference manual as well as searching on the web and could find no explanation (I am sure it is around somewhere, I simply couldn't find it).

In particular if someone could point me to the section in the reference manual that describes (what to me) seems peculiar behavior I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well dictionary keys **don't** need a 'preceding slash', but we'll come back to that.

The forward slash introduces a **literal** name object, the same name but without a '/' also introduces a name, but in this case it's an **executable** name.

You can find this on page 36 of the 3rd edition PLRM. Section 3.3.2 Attributes of Objects actually starts on page 35 but Literal and Executable attributes are described on page 36:

> • Names are literal if they are preceded by / and executable if they
> are not.

At the top of the page the action of the interpreter on encountering a literal or executable object is defined:

> • If the object is literal, the interpreter treats it strictly as data
> and pushes it on the operand stack for use as an operand of some
> subsequent operator.
>
> • If the object is executable, the interpreter executes it.

So, when you put /posX that is a literal name object, and the interpreter treats it as data, pushes it on the operand stack for later use. When you put posX that is an executable name object, so the interpreter tries to execute it.

Still on the same page (36) we see:

> • Executing an executable name causes it to be looked up in the
> current dictionary context and the associated value to be executed.

So on encountering /posX the interpreter creates a name object 'posX' and puts it on the operand stack. When encountering posX the interpreter tries to look up 'posX' as a key in the current dictionary.

Your code is:

```
/positions 1 dict def
positions begin
   /posX 200 def
end
positions posX get 100 moveto
```

You have already used `begin` on the dictionary 'positions' so it's already the current dictionary. This means that instead of using `get` to retrieve the value from 'positions' you could (and more normally in PostScript, would) do this:

```
/positions 1 dict def
positions begin
   /posX 200 def
   posX 100 moveto
end
```

Obviously the indentation there is just for emphasis, to show where the dictionary is current.

Now on to the side note. Dictionary keys do not have to be names! They almost always are, but there are times when it's useful to be able to use 'something else' as the key. To take a somewhat contrived example, let say I want to know how many pieces of text use all the fonts in a document.

```
%!
/MyDict 20 dict dup def begin
/FontNumbers 20 dict def
     
/old_show show load def
/show {
  currentfont dup
  FontNumbers known {
    dup FontNumbers get 1 add FontNumbers exch put
  }{
    FontNumbers exch 1 put
  } ifelse  
  old_show
} bind def

end
```

Now every time we use 'show' we will look for 'FontNumbers' in the current dictionary. We then use the font dictionary returned by `currentfont` as a key and look to see if that key is present in the dictionary. If it is we `get` the associated value, add 1 and `put` the new value back, again using the current font dictionary as the key. If the key isn't found then we put a key/value pair where the value is 0 and the key is the current font dictionary.

Note! I haven't tried that code and it may well have errors, it's just to illustrate the point that the key in a dictionary need not be a name, it can be an object of any type. See page 41 of the PLRM, section 3.3.9 Dictionary Objects.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it. `posX` within the `positions begin ... end` is executed and looked up in the current dictionary which is `positions`. The snippet `positions posX get` fails because `posX` is executed and is not in the current dictionary (`positions` is not the current dictionary). Thank you for the tip making me aware that normal postscript code is to enclose the action code within the dictionary.

Comment: Spot on, I'm glad you followed, I wasn't sure I was explaining terribly well.